# Another dark light problem

Tags: rendering

I have the dark light problem and can't figure out what settings are wrong. I have read about different solutions for this but none work for me. I think the scale are right but i am pretty fresh in Blender so i could be wrong. I have put a link to the file.

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N2t62_K-MSPxU0kFxtVfHDCKuixPKOMJ)

Answer (score 0):

To increase the brightness, change the strength of the lamp to a higher value.

[image]

If you want more even light, I recommend changing your light to an area.

[image]

Comment: Ok, but is not 10000 pretty high? In the tutorial the value is around 5.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rbPwn-I0oM 10000 is not high at all.

Comment: But he has 500 (500.000) i have 10000 (10000.000)

Comment: If you watch later in the video, he adds multiple area light with strengths up to 3000

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, i will experiment with it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using high values for the light, as long as you get the result you want.